# Issue in changing sticky logo to non sticky

Tags: jquery, css, gsap

I am trying to add custom CSS code to change the sticky header logo to normal using the inspect element option.

```
The CSS code will be 

.menu-sticky{
position:static;
}

even I tried using another class

.sticky-menu{
position:static;
}

both class code were not working.

website url is :  checkmate.health
```

please help me to fix this.

Comment: the css deifintion `position: static;`is the normal definition and does not actually have an influence on being sticky/static. For that you should use either `position: fixed;` or `position: sticky;`in combination with a direction and value like `.sticky-menu { position: fixed; top: 0; }`

Comment: Still it is not working, could you please check the same from your end too using inspect element to confirm and also are we using the exact class name to achieve this ? @tacoshy

Comment: for more help then this, it would be necessary to provide more then a few CSS lines and the HTML code aswell.

Comment: this looks like more than a simple css issue. your site animations run on GSAP. If you look at your body & navbar classes, there are animations running on scroll. To solve this, we'd need to see your GSAP JS files, and also your css

Comment: Hi it is a purchased theme from themeforest, we are customizing using WordPress. We need to fix using inspect element if the code works here the same should be updated in additional css file in WordPress. Can't we add the css via inspect element @idlab

Comment: ah, so you dont have access to the theme directory folder via an IDE or FTP. Normally using a css !important property will override JS scripts. Not necessarily with GSAP as those js scripts tend to replace the whole css property. From inspecting your site, to get your header "non sticky" you'll probably need to make changes to the html markup as well as the css & gsap js files, which you wont be able to do unless you have access via an IDE or FTP. You best bet is to contact the theme developer in this case.

Comment: Right now I do not have access to those theme directory folder, If I have access I have to add custom codes in those source code files ?@idlab

Answer (score -1):

You add classes to the wrong element. Add these properties to the `.navbar` element that has an absolute position. You will need to use `!important` to overwrite the default classes.

Comment: I have added  .navbar{position:static !important; }  but it does not changed. The added code view is kind of blur(hidden) not looking normal like other codes